# Use AsyncTask in multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with proper use AsyncTask. I use AsyncTask to communicate with the server. I run server connection in AsyncTask doInBackground. My app listens in the background and as soon as captured message uses publishProgress. Then I can use message in my App. In my application I am doing login to the server and if it was successful new activity will start. I need to communicate with the server also in the new activity but the connection was created in the background AsyncTask. I don't know how I can communicate through established connection in new activity. Can anyone give me advice? Thank you a lot!

Please take a look on code. I have this code in LoginUser class and after succesful login to the server new Activity starts.

```
//init
private ConnectionClass mConnectClass; 
private connectTask mTask;

//execute  connectTask
mTask = new connectTask();
mTask.execute("");

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ConnectionClass> {
    @Override
    protected ConnectionClass doInBackground(String... message) {
        Log.i("Terminal", "doInBackground.");

        mConnectClass = new ConnectionClass(
                new ConnectionClass.OnMessageReceived() {
                    @Override
                    // here the messageReceived method is implemented
                    public void messageReceived(String message) {
                        // this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                        publishProgress(message);
                    }
                });
        Log.i("Terminal", "Starting...");
        mConnectClass.connectServer();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        answerFromServer = Arrays.toString(values);
        // serverMessage.append("S: " + Arrays.toString(values) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: An `AsyncTask` is intended for short, one-time background tasks. If you establish a connection and want to keep it alive, you'll need to look into using a `Service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `AsyncTask` for this. You seem to want to hold your connection open for an extended period of time. `AsyncTask` is only supposed to be used for tasks that last [at most a few seconds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You might consider using a `Service` instead.

Comment: Thanks for ur help! I would like to ask one more question. I want to log in user to the server and then in new activity continue to communicate with the server. How u said, I should use Service and then I can hold my connection open for an extended period of time. However I need show new messages from the server to the screen. Should I use AsyncTask for show new messages inside ServiceClass? Is there any better way I can achieve this?

Comment: There are probably multiple ways to do this, but I'd consider sending a [local broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html). Since this is different question from your original, if you need any more help, it'd be best to make this a new question.